# Yesod Forms for Sum Types

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am trying to figure out how to set up Amazon Instant Payment Notification in my Yesod-based app.  (Just a few weeks until I go live...)  In any case, the idea behind that system is that they POST to a URL that I provide.  But the syntax they use seems to differ depending on whether the payment was made successfully or not (or if it's a cancellation, etc).

How should I approach this, using Yesod forms?  Should I create a form with an optional field for every possible field, and do validation after parsing the form?  Or can I somehow set up a "sum type" parser, using the Alternative class?  Or should I just use a different form parser for this part of the application?

Comment: It's hard to know what the best course of action here would be without understanding the input a bit better. My initial reaction would be to try and figure out what kind of data is being submitted using lookupFormPost, and then choose which form to use based on that.